# Can't connect Server 2019 with Hyper-v role to Hyper-v manager

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, hyper-v-manager

I've a Windows Server Core 2019 with the Hyper-V role installed. It has both an external and internal IP. I can't add it to the list of servers in Hyper-V manager on my own Windows 11. I've added ThrustedHosts on both sides. Used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUwwmwReV2o&t) guide and [Microsoft's own](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts) guide on the subject. However, I can't connect. I can RDP into the server. So why can't I add the server to Hyper-V manager? Do I've to open some specific ports?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.